# How To Delay My Floating ShareBar Till User Scrolls Down Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, floating, searchbar

I've gone through some of the tutorials here but still can't get a fix for my problem thus my posting this.

I was wondering if you could show me how to get my floating sharebar @ http://www.patchworkoftips.com/blackberry-messenger-voip-voice-calls/1983/ to only show only when the user has scrolled down like 100px of the page or gotten halfway in the article.

Here's my my sharebar css:

```
#search_bar {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0;
    width: 1082px;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #333;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Sorry I couldn't paste the sharebar code as it keeps disappearing here.

I'm a total newbie to using javascript and jquery so copy and paste solutions would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: It disappears? Please paste it over on http://gist.github.com or similar and post the link here. We'll deal with posting it here.

Comment: Here you go UdegbunamChuks... see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 100){ // The '100' can be set to what ever pixel height you want
         $('#search_bar').fadeIn('500'); // This shows the share bar
    }else{
         $('#search_bar').fadeOut('500'); // This hides the share bar
    }
});
```

Comment: @Madara: Thanks. Here's the link to the sharebar code: https://gist.github.com/4085257

Comment: Thanks for the code but how do i add this to the page? Do I add it to functions.php or what? The sharebar code is in my footer.php.

Comment: By the way I tried adding the code to my function.php but kept getting a syntax error

Comment: I just discovered it had to go in the header.php and it seems to be working but not 100%. when the page loads for the first time, the sharebar is visible but when i then scroll down it disappears and reappears later. After that when I scroll back to the top, it doesn't show again until I scroll down like 100px. I'm guessing this is a CSS issue right?

Comment: @UdegbunamChuks Yes, make sure the initial state of the share bar had  display: none;  :)

Comment: @UdegbunamChuks Your welcome man! Don't forget the accept my answer by clicking the checkmark to the upper left :)

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware I had to do that. ;)